# RegExp uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this code;

`navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1];`

For detecting browser version. This code works in IE 8 below but not on google chrome. The error in google chrome says;

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`

and it points to the line where this code belongs;

`navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1];`

Any idea how to fix this issue?

---

just to make things clear what i'm trying to accomplish here is to detect the browser version:

```
var version = navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1];

if(version <= 8.0)

{
   execute code;
}
```

Everything works fine in IE but I got an error in google chrome which is:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null**

and it points to the line where this code belongs;

**navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1];**

Answer (score 3):

`match` [can return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) `null` if regexp don't find anything. So you must first get matches and check have you any match or not. Try this:

```
var ieMatches = navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/);
var isIE = !!ieMatches[1];
```

Comment: Good answer.  Just to explain the actual problem.  Basically the [1] means you're pulling the second item from an array.  Match returns null if nothing matches, so you're trying to pull the second item from a non-array.  Hope this makes sense :)